# How to control formatting of floats with CsvHelper

Tags: c#, csvhelper

To control the format when writing datetimes one would do this

```cs
var options = new CsvHelper.TypeConversion.TypeConverterOptions { 
  Formats = new[] { 
    "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm" 
  } 
};
```

I wish to similarly specify a picture string controlling the formatting of floats. I tried this.

```cs
var options = new CsvHelper.TypeConversion.TypeConverterOptions {
  Formats = new[] {
    "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", 
    "###.#" 
  } 
};
```

but it doesn't work.

How do you associate a *format string* with `float` or `double`?

I need to force the *format* to the picture string shown in my second sample (`"###.#"`) because the *FORTRAN* program consuming the generated *CSV* is very fussy and will not accept `"245"` where it expects `"245.0"`.

Source for the consuming program is not available. Suggesting that I fix that is not helpful.

Comment: The answer to your question is available from the sample code following "I tried this". For people who don't read the sample code I have explained this in the text. I try not to provide irrelevant details like the fact that it's a FORTRAN program because people fixate on them. This is about controlling CsvHelper in C#.

Answer (score 0):

To force adding *0* need to use [zero placeholder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings):

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
    public float Value1 { get; set; }
    public double Value2 { get; set; }
}

var records = new List<Foo>
{
    new Foo { Id = 1, Name = "one", Time = DateTime.Now, Value1 = 1.123f, Value2 = 12345.789 },
    new Foo { Id = 2, Name = "two", Time = DateTime.Now, Value1 = 123f, Value2 = 44 },
};

var dt_options = new CsvHelper.TypeConversion.TypeConverterOptions { 
    Formats = new[] {  "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm" }  };
var float_options = new CsvHelper.TypeConversion.TypeConverterOptions { 
    Formats = new[] { "###.0" } };

using (var writer = new StreamWriter("file.csv"))
using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
{
    csv.Configuration.TypeConverterOptionsCache.AddOptions<DateTime>(dt_options);
    csv.Configuration.TypeConverterOptionsCache.AddOptions<float>(float_options);
    csv.Configuration.TypeConverterOptionsCache.AddOptions<double>(float_options);

    csv.WriteRecords(records);
}
```

```
Id,Name,Time,Value1,Value2
1,one,2021-01-07 20:54,1.1,12345.8
2,two,2021-01-07 20:54,123.0,44.0
```

Configure CsvWriter if required to wrap all values to quotes:

```
..
using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, 
    new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) { 
        ShouldQuote = (_, _) => true  }))
..

/*
"Id","Name","Time","Value1","Value2"
"1","one","2021-01-07 21:11","1.1","12345.8"
"2","two","2021-01-07 21:11","123.0","44.0"
*/
```

Comment: Using V27.1.1 couldn't get the compiler to recognise TypeConveterOptionsCache I think there's been some breaking changes https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues/1645